# EditText OnKeyListener with setFocus not working as per expected

Tags: android, android-edittext, onkeylistener

I am using an Android device with physical hardware keyboard.
I have two `EditTexts` (Part No and Qty) and Two `Buttons` (Reset and Save) on screen.
After user key in Qty, they want to press **Enter** key from physical keyboard to trigger "Save" function.
My current Save function will save the data to file and clear the data on screen and set the focus to Part No.

It seems like my `onKeyListener` didn't return True once it was consumed and it  trigger another Enter key action to move my cursor to Qty field (by right, it should stay in Part No field). 
I thought return True will indicate this Enter key has been consumed, am I understanding correct?

My two `EditText` are put directly under `ConstraintLayout` (not under any sub-layout).
Any idea on where my code goes wrong?

Below is my piece of code for layout.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etPart"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:maxLength="20"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/tvPart"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/etQty"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:maxLength="5"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/tvQty"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/etPart"
    android:nextFocusDown="@id/etPart"/>
```

Below is my Java code. 
This is in onCreate method.

```
etQty.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if(i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
                saveData(null);
                // I tried to use return true here, sames result, no different.
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This is the functions.

```
public void saveData(View view) {
    // check and save data to file logic.
    // ...... etc.
    mProductViewModel.insert(product);

    resetView(null);
}

 public void resetView(View view) {
    etPart.setText(null);
    etQty.setText(null);

    // I am expecting the focus will stay in Part No box but it is not. It will jump to Qty field.
    etPart.requestFocus();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking with the specialist, I came to understand that I also need to handle Action Up (Key Up) too.

Below is the working code.

```
    etQty.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if(i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP){
                saveData(null);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by soft keyboard, can you try this code?

```
etPart.requestFocus();
final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.restartInput(etPart);
imm.showSoftInput(etPart, 0);
```

Comment: thanks for your advice. I tried that and it is still the same. The cursor will stay in etPart for a few ms and then jump to etQty. (I tried to edit this comment to include your name and dont know why, I cannot use "@" to include your name. sorry about that).

Comment: Try `setText("")` instead of null

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. I tried with setText("") and it still the same.

Comment: Ok, last solution I can spot is that you put `return true` inside `if(i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){` and combine with all my suggestions to see if it works

Comment: I just did and it still the same (FYI: I am using an industrial android barcode terminal with hardware keypad, not sure is it because the way company design their hardware key cause this issue or purely my program error, I tried several ways I can find online and in this stackoverflow, all seems not working). I will create a simple mock up of my application and will try again (hope it just some of my setting or layout got mess up).

Comment: I did a simple mockup of my project and it still the same. My repo on github is https://github.com/scsfdev/TestKey  it seems like it may be hardware issue. any other suggestions/